# Data bound element not rendering child element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I'm trying to use knockout to bind some colors and content. Here is the html I have at the moment

```
<ul class="simple-data" data-bind="foreach: chartLegendInfo">
    <li data-bind="text: Key">
           <span class="legend-swatch" data-bind="style: { background_color: $parent.Value }"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What's happening is that the `<li>` element text is rendering properly, but the inner `<span>` is not rendering at all. No errors are being output. I'm assuming that this has something to do with the way that knockout renders inner html, so the span html is probably getting overwritten by the text bound to the `<li>`.

Does anyone know how to get around this or achieve this effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data bound to the li is being set as the innerHTML of that li, so the span is deleted. The best way to handle this is using two spans inside if the li:

```
<ul class="simple-data" data-bind="foreach: chartLegendInfo">
<li>
       <span data-bind="text: Key"></span>
       <span class="legend-swatch" data-bind="style: { background_color: $parent.Value }"></span>
</li>
```

Comment: True, or you could work with the virtual `<!-- ko -->` delimiters for the text binding